# Python: Calling local function when an imported module has a function with same name

Tags: python, python-2.7, squish

I have imported a file `common.py` into the `copyPasteAnywhereTest.py` file. `common.py` has some common functions defined in it that I need to call in the current file viz. `copyPasteAnywhereTest.py`. But there is one particular function `copyText()` that I have defined in both the files. By default, `copyText()` from `common.py` is being called. I want to call the function that I have defined locally and not the one that I defined in the imported file. The code is something like below:

This is one file `common.py`

```
#common.py

def copyText():
    #Function definition

#Some more functions defined in this file.
```

This is the script file `copyPasteAnywhereTest.py`

```
#copyPasteAnywhereTest.py

import os
import sys

sys.path.append(os.path.abspath("../z_common/"))

import common

def main():
    #some code
    copyText()    #Calling the copyText() function

def copyText():
    #Code here.
```

`copyText()` from `common.py` was called whether I imported using `import common` or `from common import functionName`

The simplest solution was to change the name of `copyText()` in `copyPasteAnywhereTest.py` and call the same. But I want to know the proper solution and not a workaround.

Just to be clear, I had't even imported the `copyText()` function in `copyPasteAnywhereTest.py` (i.e., `from common import copyText`) earlier while using the `from module import function` syntax. I have just imported the required functions using `from common import *functionName*`.

P.S. - I am quite new to Python. Don't mind if the question is a stupid one. I've tried googling and searching over the internet but I couldn't find an answer. Hence, the question.

Comment: @BlackBear: I just used it to be specific. I didn't want to import `copyText()`. Thanks. Will keep your point in mind.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. Please post a simple [mcve] that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: `from common import functionName`, will **only** import `functionName`, it will _not_ import any other names from the `common` module. In particular, it will not import the `copyText` from `common`. And if you have `from common import copyText` and then later in your script you have `def copyText():` the name `copyText` will be bound to your local function, not the imported one. But if you do `def copyText():` _before_ you do `from common import copyText` (which you should not do) then the name `copyText` will be bound to the function imported from `common`.

Comment: @PM2Ring: I have made changes to my question and I think that should help. Please note that while using `from _module_ import _function_` I never actually imported `copyText()` from `common.py`. That's why it's all the more confusing.

Comment: Thanks for posting the example code.  I can't reproduce the problem you describe (by calling main()). Are you reassigning the name copyText anywhere?  How do you know the wrong function is being called?

Comment: @snakecharmerb - I am not reassigning the name copyText anywhere. And how the wrong function is being called is what I want to know.

Comment: Sorry the second part of my comment wasn't clear. I meant to ask, have you verified that `common.copyText` is really being  called, for example by adding different `print` statements to each function?

Comment: @snakecharmerb - `common.Text()` copies text from a certain range in my AUT. But in the script `copyPasteAnyywhereTest.py` I want text from a different range to be copied. Hence, I defined a separate local function with the same name. But while running the script, I noticed that text from the same range was being copied common to other scripts which was not what I wanted. Changing the name of the local `copyText()` and and calling the same produced the desired results. This is how I deduced that `common.copyText()` was being called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than importing like this:

`from common import copyText`

do

`import common`

and in your code prefix it with the module name and a dot:

`result = common.copyText()`

By importing just the module, and referring to its contents using dotted notation you prevent these name collisions in your modules namespace.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Will keep it in mind. As far as the solution to my problem is concerned. I had initially used `import common` only. It didn't work and I changed it to `from common import *functionName*`. I tried it again just now (just to be sure) and it didn't work for me. I don't want `common.copyText()` to be called. Is there something like `this.copyText()` that I can use?

Comment: Please add an [mcve] to your question so that we can reproduce your problem.

Comment: @MayankChoudhary: If you import with just `import common`, than common's `copyTest` will not overwrite the one defined in the current module, so you can just do `copyText` for this one, and `common.copyText` for the one in `common`.

Comment: When you do "from module import function"  you are explicitly requesting to overwrite the local namespace for the object named 'function'. You can only get a pointer to the local function by importing it again, you could use my_local_copyTExt. = imp.load_source('module.name', '/path/to/file.py'). Anyway you should rethink your application, because whatever you are trying to achieve , looks hard to understand.

Comment: @snakecharmerb - I have made changes to my question. Please have a look.

Comment: @JoãoPinto - I had mentioned in the question, I wasn't using `from common import copyText`. Now that I'm using `import common` (following suggestions offered), the problem persists. Can you help me with it please?

Comment: I can repro the same behavior. If you just use "import module_name" on top of the file and you happen to have functions with same name in both files (current and module_name) then the function from module_name is run. Is there an order due to which function from the current file is overridden ? Is there something like a "this" pointer ?